# Exception when running JavaFX app using Hibernate on Android

Tags: java, android, hibernate, javafxports

I have a JavaFX desktop application. It accesses a remote MySQL database via Hibernate and LAN/WiFi.
I now try to port it with an as small as possible effort to Android 8.1 using Gluon mobile/javafxports.

When running the app on Android I get the following exception:

```
Could not parse configuration: commonhibernate.cfg.xml 
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2105)
```

**EDIT**: Content of commonhibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
    ~ ...
    -->
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping resource="Gender.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Person.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

On the (Windows-)PC the application runs well without this exception.

From other posts here on stackoverflow I understand that there is doubt that Hibernate can/should be used on Android.
But since these posts are 5 years old or older, I like to ask whether this is still the case and if someone can help regarding abbove exception on Android ?

Comment: share the contents of `commonhibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Ok, will edit my post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the connection parameters.

Here example of configuration:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">URL_CONNECTION</property>
        <property name="connection.username">YOUR_USERNAME</property>
        <property name="connection.password">YOUR_PASSWORD</property>

        <mapping resource="Gender.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="Person.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: My Hibernate configuration is spread over a few files, commonhibernate.cfg.xml just happens to be the first one that is read. The file containing the connection params is read later. This did not cause any problems in the existing JavaFX desktop application.